# My notebook is almost full

Tags: word-choice, words, phrase-requests

So I was trying to ask for a new notebook at my office, I wanted to say that my notebook is almost full, so I need a new one.

I ended up saying

> 私のノートはページがあまり残っていませんので、新しいノートをお願いします。

But I don't know if there is a better way to say it, a more natural way.

Thank you!

Comment: what you mean? the storage is almost full?

Comment: From the phrasing, I assume OP means a (paper) notebook, not a PC.

Comment: @jogloran i misread "new one" as "new device", somehow, my bad.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I meant a paper notebook!

Comment: I think ノートが切れる would be a possible translation. 切れる(https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/#je-18772) has the meaning of running out of something.

Comment: Wouldn't 手帳 be a better choice? I'd assume the OP meant a PC too, if there was only the Japanese to go by.

Comment: @CharlesReisRibeiro ノートが切れた means "the notebook was (physically) cut" or "we ran out of the stock of notebooks".

Answer (score 4):

You can use the no-adjective いっぱい. You can translate "to become full (with ～)" as (～で)いっぱいになる.

- ホテルが予約でいっぱいになりました。
  The hotel was fully booked.
- そのことで頭がいっぱいだ。
  My head is full of that.
- トウモロコシでいっぱいのトラック
  a truck full of corn

You can say ノートがほとんどいっぱいになりました. ノートのページがあまり残っていません is perfectly natural, too.

Answer (score 3):

ノートのページがあまり残っていない is not bad. You can also say ノートがもうすぐ終わる.